# How to call a method to query a table using java?

Tags: java, jdbc

i have a utility code to connect a database and to query a database. After calling the method to connect the database, i don't know how to call the method to query the table.

Here is the code to query:

```
public static ResultSet getData(Connection con){

        ResultSet resultreport = null;
        try{
        PreparedStatement pmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT NAME, AGE FROM EMPLOYEE");
        resultreport = pmt.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(resultreport.getString(1) + " " + resultreport.getString(2) );
        } catch (SQLException e) {  
                     e.printStackTrace();       
                 }
                return resultreport;   
            }
```

when i try this, i don't know what to insert the bracket:
 Utility.getData(...);

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for JDBC? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/

Comment: Try this tutorial, http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/ this might help you.

Comment: Yes this is what i used

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass a connection object to the method.

for example.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = null;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname","username", "password");
```

Then call method

```
   Utility.getData(conn);
```

Comment: This part is done in Utility code but i cannot call with the method Utility.getData(con); it s asking me to create a local variable con